# Why Copy Table from Excel Turns as Picture Format in Body Email

Tags: microsoft-excel, email

why suddenly i copy a table from excel and paste into body email it turns to be a picture format? i want it as a table format
Please help

[enter image description here][1]

Comment: Close Excel after copying from it, but before pasting into email. CSV will be pasted. Then convert it into table if possible. *why ... it turns to be a picture format?* Excel Range is not compatible with your email interface possibilities I think.

Comment: What kind of Excel file format did you copy? What's the email message Text Format? How did you paste Table?